# can't get input value in iframe page and get to parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have tried the tutorial are there, but still could not work, what's wrong with my code?

Parent Page Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#iframe1").contents().find("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            alert('Hello');
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Iframe script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="nominal" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

please tell me what was wrong, thanks advance.

Comment: Both parent page and iframe.html are in the same domain/protocol/port ?

Comment: yup it's same @Luca

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script>
var money = 20000;
function my_custom_function(input)
{
    // remove possible existing message
    if( input.next().is("form") ) input.next().remove();
    // show message
    if( input.val() > money ) alert('Hello');
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your iframe code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#nominal").change("change", function() {
                parent.my_custom_function($(this));
            });
            $("#nominal").change("keyup", function() {
                parent.my_custom_function($(this));
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="nominal" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this trick will be helpful to you.

Comment: you can try by your self

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible scenarios:

1. if you can modify iframe page;
2. if you can't.

Your problem is that when your javascript run, the content of iframe could be not available, so JQuery cannot "attach" to child controls.
If you can change your iframe code, you can add this script to your iframe page

```
window.onload = function() {
    parent.iframeLoaded();
}
```

and obviously on the parent page you must change your code to

```
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    window.iframeLoaded = function() {
    $("#iframe1").contents().find('#nominal').on('keyup', null, function(event)    {
                var input = $(this);
                // show message
                if( input.val() > money )
                    alert('Hello');
        });
        }
    });
});
```

If you instead cannot change iframe html, you cannot bind to keyup event of controls but you can bind to iframe one, so in this case you need to bind keyup of iframe and then filter for #nominal originated event, and your code should be like this

```
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

        $("#iframe1").contents().on('keyup', null, function(event) {
            if(event.target.id === 'nominal'){
                var input = $("#iframe1").contents().find('#nominal');
                // show message
                if( input.val() > money )
                    alert('Hello');
            }
        });
});
```